# Queston about GRUB2 + UEFI

Tags: grub2

So I had my whole system set on legacy mode. But I switched to UEFI for no particular reason, just to see if I can. My Laptop is a dual-boot with both Ubuntu 16.10 and Windows 10.

I converted the MBR partition to GPT, but neither grub or Ubuntu ere starting. I was directly singed in into W10.

After a bit of search and some wrong commands that got me nowhere I managed to fix it.

But my problem is that grub looks like this now:

[image]

Is this how it should look?

I used this post as a guide: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2223856&s=a9f66fd7505b24d718302f86f39e85bb&p=13025073#post13025073

Until the last command it was working, but after that it didn't. I used boot repair in the end and everything was fixed. But I got that weird text when grub is starting.

Comment: When the computer is booting reliably, I don't think you need to worry about some weird text :-)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It was just weird seeing it there, lol.

Comment: That's what it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Open your search dash and type `grub customizer`.

If you do not have it, install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install grub-customizer
```

From there you can grafically customize your grub. You can also edit the entries. Remember to save a few older kernels.